# Handle User Inactivity and Logout in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wanted to refresh the token every 1 hour ONLY if there is a user activity.
Otherwise just remove the token.

Currently, my code below does call the refresh api every 1 hour regardless whether there is user activity or not.

User activity is any movement on your keyboard or mouse.

```
const App = () => {
  const refreshTokenInterval = () => {
    try {
      const isLoggedIn = useAuthStore.getState().isLoggedIn;
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        AuthenticationService.refresh(null, (response) =>
          CookieService.set(activeAccount, response.data)
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setTimeout(refreshTokenInterval, 1000 * 60 * 60);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    refreshTokenInterval();
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What's your definition of user activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've abstracted the logic into a hook. The basic logic is based on a running interval that calls the `refreshTokenInterval` handler once every hour (or any interval you need), and event listeners that detect if there was any activity at all during the previous interval's duration. If there was activity the the `refreshTokenInterval` completes the token refresh logic, otherwise if there was no activity `refreshTokenInterval` kills the running interval and clears the activity event listeners.

Code:

```js
const INTERVAL_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 60;

const events = [
  "mousedown",
  "mousemove",
  "wheel",
  "keydown",
  "touchstart",
  "scroll"
  // ... add other events here ...
];

const addListeners = (events, cb) => {
  events.forEach((event) =>
    window.addEventListener(event, cb, { passive: true })
  );

  return () => {
    events.forEach((event) =>
      window.removeEventListener(event, cb, { passive: true })
    );
  };
};

const useRefreshTokenInterval = (activeAccount, interval = INTERVAL_TIME) => {
  const intervalRef = React.useRef();
  const unlistenRef = React.useRef();
  const wasActiveRef = React.useRef(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const refreshTokenInterval = (initial) => {
      if (!initial && !wasActiveRef.current) {
        // Inactive, clearing interval, not refreshing token
        CookieService.remove(activeAccount);
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        if (unlistenRef.current) {
          unlistenRef.current();
        }
        return;
      }
      try {
        const isLoggedIn = useAuthStore.getState().isLoggedIn;
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          // Attempting token refresh
          AuthenticationService.refresh(null, (response) =>
            CookieService.set(activeAccount, response.data)
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
        // Reset activity for next interval
        wasActiveRef.current = false;
      }
    };

    refreshTokenInterval(true); // <-- initial call

    // Setup token refresh interval
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(refreshTokenInterval, interval);

    // Add activity event listeners
    unlistenRef.current = addListeners(events, () => {
      // There was some activity
      wasActiveRef.current = true;
    });

    // Return cleanup function to clear any running interval timer
    // and unsubscribes event listeners
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
      if (unlistenRef.current) {
        unlistenRef.current();
      }
    };
  }, [activeAccount, interval]);
};
```

Usage:

```js
useRefreshTokenInterval("account"); // <-- I've no idea what activeAccount is ‍♂️
```

In this example I extracted `activeAccount` as an external dependency, so this value may need to be memoized in order to provide it as a stable reference since it is referenced in a `useEffect` hook's dependency array.

### Demo

Here's a demo using a 10 second token refresh/activity interval.

[image: Edit handle-user-inactivity-and-logout-in-react]

Comment: @Joseph Do you need to remove the token when the interval has expired and the token will not be refreshed? If so then you would call that line in the `// Inactive, clearing interval, not refreshing token` if-block. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Joseph I guess your environment doesn't understand Optional Chaining, I've updated to use a null-check instead.

Comment: This should be extended with additional checks for `document.visibilityState` and `document.hasFocus()`. The `mousemove` for example event is also triggered when the document isn't active and has no focus. There are also interactions that can't be captured with events, they just won't fire correctly. For example, switching directly between at least two iframes that are next to each other without a gap, so that `mousemove` couldn't trigger, focus and blur-events won't fire in this situation either, which means, you might also be forced to monitor `document.activeElement`.

Comment: @Christopher That's true. The events that constitute "activity" isn't exhaustive list in my example, and isn't the main topic OP is needing help with. This is meant to be a starting off point.

Comment: @Joseph the `visibilityState` and `hasFocus()` conditions could be added easily to the callback function: `if (document.visibilityState == "visible" && document.hasFocus()) { wasActiveRef.current = true; }`, monitoring the activeElement as mentioned, is a really rare use case, most of the time it would be enough to add a `"focus"` and `"blur"`-handler to the event list.

Comment: @Joseph Mostly from experience (*I guess ‍♂️*). Are you really asking how to look up what [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#event_listing) you can listen for? The few I included are just some of the common, obvious events that indicate user interactions with the page/app, you can expand, or narrow, the list of events you care about to suit your app's needs.

Answer (score 0):

This will refresh your token once every time user is inactive for 1 hour if my define of your user activity is right

```
const [isInActive, setIsInActive] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  activityWatcher();
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener();
  };
}, [activityWatcher]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isInActive) {
    refreshTokenInterval();
    setIsInActive(false);
  }
}, [isInActive]);

const activityWatcher = useCallback(() => {
  var secondsSinceLastActivity = 0;

  var maxInactivity = 3600;

  setInterval(function () {
    secondsSinceLastActivity++;
    if (secondsSinceLastActivity > maxInactivity) {
      setIsInactive(true);
      secondsSinceLastActivity = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);

  function activity() {
    secondsSinceLastActivity = 0;
  }

  var activityEvents = [
    "mousedown",
    "mousemove",
    "keydown",
    "scroll",
    "touchstart",
  ];

  activityEvents.forEach(function (eventName) {
    document.addEventListener(eventName, activity, true);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Where do I call the AuthenticationService.refresh here?

Comment: You have defined it in refreshTokenInterval function, why do you need to call it again?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the below solution

```
  import { useIdleTimer } from "react-idle-timer";

  const FIVE_MINS = 5 * 60 * 1000;
  const GENERAL_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 500;

   /**
   * SET USER IDEAL TIME WITH DEBOUNCE
   */
  useIdleTimer({
    timeout: FIVE_MINS, // time in millisecond
    onIdle: handleOnUserIdle,
    debounce: GENERAL_DEBOUNCE_TIME, // time in millisecond
  });
```

Above code you could add to Parent component. It will track the user activity in case user was not active for more than certain time it will trigger the onIdle function. Where you can add your logic related to refresh token

NPM - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-idle-timer?activeTab=readme

Comment: Can you refactor my code with that?

Comment: remove the set timeout code from the refreshTokenInterval function and call it on onIdle. it should solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

you can use useEffect in setTimeout function and time set 1 hour